# The connection point "BDWP item"" on "g_GUID" is disabled

Tags: sharepoint-2013, external-contenttype

When I add a new external content type in designer and press "create profile pages" it gives me the error "the connnection point "BDWP Item" on "g_(guid)" is disabled.

I've looked in central admin and it gives me exact same error pointing to some webpart pages error.

I've looked on the net and found one reference to this error claiming it has to do with the difference between foundation and enterprise however, i am on enterprise (enterprise license).

Any clues?